# How can I get the attribute of a selected key in the graph editor in Maya

Tags: python, maya, mel

I need to get the attribute from a key (or keys) selected in the graph editor. Preferably in Python. I was trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXzIxBFW5Ps) to figure it out in MEL, but unfortunately when I try it, it just gets me all of the attributes instead of just the selected one.

This was my attempt in Python

```
import pymel.core as pm
objects=pm.ls(sl=1)
attrs=pm.selectionConnection('graphEditor1FromOutliner', q=1, object=1)
for attr in attrs:
    buffer = []
    buffer=attr.split(".")
    attribute=buffer[1]
    print attribute
```

I'm still relatively new to Python, so any help would be appreciated! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use the keyframe command to get what you need? From MEL, with keys selected in the Graph Editor and running this command, you get the Return below, showing the attributes of the selected keys following an under_score.

Not sure how you would integrate this into your Python script, but hopefully it's a start...

```
keyframe -sl -q -attribute -name;
//Result pCube1_translateX pCube1_translateY pCube1_rotateY
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your issue.

```
import pymel.core as pm
objects=pm.ls(sl=1)
attrs = pm.selectionConnection('graphEditor1FromOutliner', q=1, object=1)
buffer = []

for attr in attrs:   
    buffer = attr.split(".")
    buffer = buffer[1]
    print buffer
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).